# NODEJS on simple SQL query fetching from the local database and displaying on local system

Tags: node.js

**I am trying to display data in JSON format on the browser! any suggestions .... i have given my javascript (.js) code below**

---

1. I am trying to execute this simple query using nodeJS but it dosent
   seem to work There is no password for the database
2. ALL i am trying to do is display the answer in JSON format on the
   local brower fetched from the mysql database which is also on the
   local system
3. I have a database named **node** and table named **test** already
   created in local system it has just two fields named **id** and
   **content**

---

```
var http = require('http'),
   mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
database: 'node'
});

http.createServer(function (request, response) 
{
   request.on('end', function () 
   {   
      connection.query('SELECT id, content FROM test WHERE id IN (?, ?)',[1, 2], function(error, rows, fields)
      {
         response.writeHead(200);

         response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
      });
   });

}).listen(8080);
```

**my problem is :: nodejs server is running but i am not able to display JSON data on the browser** ... any suggestions on how to resolve it !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

---

***This is a 100% working code for your question ! !***

---

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'node'
});

console.log('MySQL Connection details  '+connection);

http.createServer(function (request, response) 
{ 
        console.log('Creating the http server');
        connection.query('SELECT id, content FROM test WHERE id IN (?,?)',[1, 2], function(err, rows, fields)
        {
                console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
                response.end();
        }); 

}).listen(8084);
```

I have even added the snapshot's below

---

**`command prompt where the execution is done below`**

---

[image: image1]

---

**`JSON output seen in the browser below`**

---

[image: image2]

Comment: you are the node master

Answer (score 0):

Add a content-type in your code:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: @ Krampstudio ... I tried but still no result any other solutions ? .....browser keeps on loading but in the end it times out !

Comment: what does display `console.log(JSON.stringify(rows)))`; ?

Comment: this simple test works: 
`var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response){
   request.on('end', function (){   
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end("{'ok' : true}");
   });
}).listen(4000);`

Comment: @ Krampstudio ..... Both the cases ... there is same behavior from the browser ! .....

Comment: @ Krampstudio ...... I tried the code but i need to create JSON output so stringify is a must ..... i am able to connect to the server in other scenarios.... having problems with this code

Comment: try to display the content of `error` and `rows` in the console before sending the response.

Comment: @ krampstudio .... I dont have sufficient points to promote answers ... but just wanted to say ..... your sugestions did help me understand the NODEJS better than before .. thanks !