# How to make this NODEJS program a webservice

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

**I am a newbie to NODEJS, Java-script programming, so learning the basics**

- I have given the simple code sample below, how to make this a web
  service, this code does connect to the database and result a JASON
  output how to make this a web-service

*I am planning to host this code in AWS and call it from my computer through the internet connection*

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'node'
});

console.log('MySQL Connection details  '+connection);

http.createServer(function (request, response) 
{ 
        console.log('Creating the http server');
        connection.query('SELECT id, content FROM test WHERE id IN (1, 2)', function(err, rows, fields)
        {
                console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
                //response.end();
        }); 

}).listen(8084);
```

**Any links or guidance would help also!!**

Thanks !!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471334/nodejs-on-simple-sql-query-fetching-from-the-local-database-and-displaying-on-lo?rq=1, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471334/nodejs-on-simple-sql-query-fetching-from-the-local-database-and-displaying-on-lo?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Consider using express (http://expressjs.com/). You can find a nice tutorial there : http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/.